# ssh_init: host does not exist.. trying to copy tomcat7 folder to my ubuntu EC2 instance usign PSCP

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, amazon-ec2, putty, pscp

My Ubuntu

```
   ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-180:~$ sudo su
    root@ip-172-31-81-180:/home/ubuntu#
```

CMD prompt:

```
C:\Users\gsrte\Downloads>pscp C:\Users\gsrte\Downloads\tomcat7.zip ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-180:/home/ubuntu/tomcat7
```

Error:

```
ssh_init: Host does not exist
```

Can anyone please explain the error ssh_init. I have started the ec2 on public instance, then using putty I have connected to the ubuntu server using username ubuntu and also `sudo su` root user. Any idea for the root cause of the `ssh_init: host does not exist error`? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because that's actually your servers `hostname`, not it's IP address.

Most hostnames are pretty simple, for example, stackoverflow.com, consisting of a name, and a Top Level Domain or TLD, in this case the name is stackoverflow and the TLD is .com

With your example, `ip-172-31-81-180`, you have what could be a valid domain **name** but no TLD, but you need to keep in mind, on linux servers, your hostname can be anything you want, I could make my server's hostname say, for example, whitehouse.gov, but that doesn't mean it is :)

That being said, i'd assume that your server's hostname is, in fact, derived from the real IP, and thus your IP address for that server is probably `172.31.81.180`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, I have also seen this error when a server is password protected and the incorrect password was entered. Perhaps check to make sure you don't need a password to connect, and if you do check that the password is being sent to the server correctly.